# java.util.Base64 decode then encode yields different string

Tags: java, base64

The issue: decoding Fz+= then encoding it back yields Fz8=

The following code:

```
new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(Base64.getDecoder().decode("Fz+=".getBytes("UTF-8"))))
```

Gives the following String:
    **Fz8=**

How did the + become an 8?

I must be missing something here.

Fz+= in bit pattern: 000101 110011 111110 000000

rearranged in 8bit groups: 00010111 00111111 10000000

In decimal: 23 63 128

which would need 3 bytes to represent it.

However when I try just this code:

```
Base64.getDecoder().decode("Fz+=".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

I get the following array in decimal:

```
 [23, 63]
```

Where did the last byte (1000 0000) go ? It's the reason the + turned into an 8 when we encoded it.

Comment: Seems like round-trip data loss stemming from the `UTF-8` conversion? Not entirely sure but [this](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/) article might be helpful. Looks like it has to do with how the `128` is expanded to multiple bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input string `Fz+=` is not a valid Base64 encoding.

By definition, if the encoded string ends with a single padding character, the input that resulted in that encoding quartet contained only two bytes.  When encoding, the two-byte input was supposed to be padded with `0x00` to make a full 3-byte unit that was then encoded to 4 Base64 code bytes.

Whatever produced the string `Fz+=` incorrectly padded the 2-byte input with `0x80`.  Alternatively, the encoder mistook the `0x80` for `0x00` possibly because it was expecting pure 7-bit ASCII.

Regardless of the reason, the `Fz+=` input is invalid, and the decoder just ignored the extra two bits.

If the input really was `00010111 00111111 10000000`, then the proper encoding is `Fz+A` with no padding and the `A` code representing `000000`.  Again, this is likely due to a bug in whatever originally did the encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was not aware of that. Does that mean that the correct base64 encoding of 00010111 00111111 10000000 for example would be Fz+A ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I edited my answer shortly after posting. Makes a lot of sense.